# SSH multiple queries

Tags: sql

I want to run multiple SQL queries at once on SSH.  I am using putty. Is this the correct syntax?

```
DELETE FROM table1 where date = '2011-12-31';
DELETE FROM table1 where date = '2012-12-31';
```

Comment: That looks reasonable for most databases, although running the exact same `delete` query twice doesn't really make sense.

Comment: what does ssh have to do with this?

Comment: You mean in a sql terminal, ssh doesn't really have anything to do with it. Yes, you separate sql queries with a semi colon in most flavours. Have you tried it out?

Comment: I am using putty for the first time.  I was used to running php queries on PHPMyadmin.  I am not sure of how to input the SQL queries, it is very new to me.

Answer (score 0):

This includes a code sample, so is too long for a comment.

Why run two queries?  Just do:

```
DELETE FROM table1 where date in ('2011-12-31', '2012-12-31');
```

I'm not sure what the "ssh" interface is to a database (I know what ssh is and I know how databases interface to the rest of the world).  In some interfaces, you are limited to a single query per call.

Also, although your syntax is correct, you could have various problems.  For instance, Oracle doesn't recognize YYYY-MM-DD strings as being dates (unless you include the keyword `date` first).  Sometimes a "date" field in a database has a time component.  You will probably not get a match if that is the case in your database.

Comment: The date field in my table is in the syntax yyyy-mm-dd